# How to iterate through an API response and assign response value to nested array in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, http, typescript-generics

I'm trying to make API call several time in a loop and at the response, I assign the project id back to the array but the value of m incremented already before running the second  loop and that throws an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'imagesnamearray' of undefined.

```
var  m = 0;
for (var j=0 ; j<this.imagesdataarray.length;j++){
  var n=0;
  for (var i=0;i<this.imagesdataarray[j].imagesnamearray.length;i++){
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('userID',this.userid );
    fd.append('projectID', this.imagesdataarray[j].projectid);
    fd.append('id',this.imagesdataarray[j].imagesnamearray[i].imageid);
    fd.append('formFiles', this.imagesdataarray[j].imagesnamearray[i].image );

    this.http.post('http://api.interiordesigns2020.com/api/services/app/ImageProject/CreateProjectImages',fd)
    .subscribe(async (res) => {
      this.data=res;
      this.imagesdataarray[m].imagesnamearray[n].imageid=this.data.result; 
      n++;
    });
    
  }
  m++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `m` is a global variable and your callback (the argument to `subscribe`) is executed asynchronously.

Your code first creates a lot of HTTP requests, increasing `m` and `n` in the process. Sometimes later, the HTTP requests complete and your callback is called. By that time, `m` no longer has the value it had when you started the request.

I would rewrite your code as follows. I have also replaced your `for` loop with `Array.forEach`.

```js
this.imagesdataarray.forEach(imagedata => {
  imagedata.imagesnamearray.forEach(imagename => {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('userID', this.userid );
    fd.append('projectID', imagedata.projectid);
    fd.append('id', imagename.imageid);
    fd.append('formFiles', imagename.image);

    this.http
      .post('http://api.interiordesigns2020.com/api/services/app/ImageProject/CreateProjectImages', fd)
      .subscribe(data => {
        imagename.imageid = data.result; 
      });
  })
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help man but I still have one issue the HTTP request still not wait for API response the imageid assigned to image name is not correct.

Comment: You mean you want to wait until all HTTP request have completed? That requires a different setup. Take a look at [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin).